# How to get response status code in axios? Standard solutions doesn't work

Tags: axios

I have this axios code and I can't reach response status code. What is wrong here? I get 'undefined' instead of 201, for example.

Thanks in advance!

```
  axios.post('endpoint', { body })
    .then((response) => {
        console.log(response.status);
    })
```

Comment: Give a [mre]; what's Api? That should work with Axios, unless you've configured it somewhere.

Comment: @jonrsharpe sorry. edited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of error you have to `catch` the result

```
axios.post('endpoint', { body })
    .then((response) => {
        // do something
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error.response.status)
    })
```

Comment: i get error code 500 and in this case code inside .then is running

Comment: In this case `response.status` should work. Can you share the response object?

Comment: For me the response is just "false" in case of a 404 response

Answer (score 0):

```
    post(endpoint, body) {
        return axios.post(endpoint, body)
          .then((response) => {
            return { 
               error: null, 
               data: response.data, 
               status: response.status 
             };
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            return { error: error };
      });
  }
```